# Ubuntu SMBus Host Controller not enabled! Problem

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, virtual-machine

can anyone help me to solve this problem with my Ubuntu VM machine.

I try do add some space to it but it didn't solve it.

it has :
7GB Ram
26GB hard disk
8 coeurs cpu